# How to add checkbox to datatable in meteorjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, datatable

I am using the aldeed tabular package for my datatable:

https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/tabular

and I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out how to add a checkbox to for each record in the datatable? So far I have been able to define and add regular data columns, but not tables. So far my table columns are defined as:

```
  optionsObject: {
    columns: [
      {
        title: 'Description',
        data: 'description',
        className: 'nameColumn'
      }, {
        title: 'size',
        data: 'size',
        className: 'nameColumn'
      },

      {
        title: 'check1',
        type: 'checkbox',
        separator: "",
        options: [
        { label: '', value: 1}]

      }

    ]
  }
```

Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
{
  title: 'check1',
  type: 'checkbox',
  separator: "",
  options: [
  { label: '', value: 1}]
}
```

use

```
{
  tmpl: Meteor.isClient && Template.datatableCheckboxCell
}
```

Populate the cell with a template and put your checkbox handler there.

```
<template name="datatableCheckboxCell">
  <!-- put checkbox here -->
</template>
```

The cell is given the context of the row's data, so you can use "this._id" from within its event handler.